# Android Internal Storage Video play using VideoView, Can't use seekTo(int)

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, seektotime

I have stored some video files in android internal private storage and I 
loaded those videos using android `VideoView`. And then I tried to open last position of the video with `onResume()`.

I got the last position of the video using `videoView.getCurrentPosition()` (it comes as a int value).

I used `videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);` to access last position.
And Couldn't see good out put and the video getting crash with showing the error "can't play this video".

I need to load the video from last viewed position with `onResume()` method.

I am using 23 as the compileSdkVersion.

Sample code:

---

```
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        videoViewAction = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoview_action);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager
        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.setMediaController(null);
        final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

        String path;
        try {
            path = getIntent().getExtras().get("url").toString();

            videoView.setVideoPath(path);
            videoView.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int p = 1;
        }
            // rawer object Assigned to the view
        videoViewAction.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (flag == true) {
                            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                            mediaController.hide();
                            flag = false;
                        } else if (flag == false) {
                            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                            mediaController.show();
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }

            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

       /* VideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));*/
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(stopPosition == 0)
                {
                    videoView.start();
                }
                else {
                    videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                    videoView.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_video, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (id) {

            case android.R.id.home:

                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_chapters:
                Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    videoView.resume();
    super.onResume();
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
    videoView.start();
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        //super.onPause();
        stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition(); //stopPosition is an int
       // videoView.pause();
        videoView.suspend();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Can anyone please give a good solution for this issue? Or Any other way to do that positioning?